# rails 3 label i18n unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, label

i want to translate a model attribute (post.name). in my view i have

```
label :post, :name
```

in my en.yml i have

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        name: "Test"
```

it works only if i use it in the post-view, but in other views is does not (label-text is "Name" there). Is this intended behavior (this restriction is not mentioned in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label)), and can i do something about it?

Comment: thx fl00r for ultra-fast edit

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game here, just came across your question looking for an answer to another.

Here you go: `label :post, :name, Post.human_attribute_name(:name)`